# How to get all possible combinations of directories from a URL

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I'm having trouble figuring out an algorithm to detect reoccurring directory patterns in lists of urls, can anyone suggest a method for this? Im pretty sure it will need to be a recursive call but I cant decide how to hold records for each possible pattern.

**Note**: This is in PHP.

Lests say you have some urls:

```
1. http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/chocolate-pie.html
2. http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/cherry-pie.html
3. http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/apps/chex-mix.html
4. http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/soup/tomato.html
5. http://www.goodfood.com/special/special_occasion/soup/beef-stew.html
6. http://www.goodfood.com/special/special_occasion/soup/vegetable.html
```

I would like to find a way to determine all possible patterns of directories that more than one url has. So the results would look something like this:

```
'recipes/special_occasion' is found in urls 1, 2, 3 and 4.
'recipes/special_occasion/desserts' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'special_occasion/desserts/pie' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'desserts/pie' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'special_occasion/desserts' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'special_occasion/desserts/pie' is found in urls 1, and 2.
'special/special_occasion' is found in urls 5, and 6.
'special/special_occasion/soup' is found in urls 5, and 6.
'special_occasion/soup' is found in urls 5, and 6.
```

My idea is to go through each url and pull out every possible new pattern and store it in an array. So far I have: 
         $commonDomains = array();

```
     foreach($query AS $row) {


         $urlPath = parse_url($row['href'], PHP_URL_PATH);
         echo "$urlPath<br/>";

         $urlChunks = explode('/', $urlPath);
         //var_dump($urlChunks);

         foreach($urlChunks AS $domain) {
             if(strlen($domain) > 0) {
                $thisDomain = $domain.'/';
                $commonDomains[$thisDomain][] = $row['id'];
             }
         }
         var_dump($commonDomains);
     }
```

Has anyone run across this before? It screams pattern at me but I cant find an answer online as of yet. Everything I think of gets very complicated very fast. Please help, thank you.

---

I have an example of what Im working on: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kn4-zyh

Heres my results so far

```
/recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html
array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "recipes" [1]=> string(16) "special_occasion" [2]=> string(8) "desserts" [3]=> string(3) "pie" [4]=> string(27) "grandmas-chocolate-pie.html" } 

0 : 4 : recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html
0 : 3 : recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie
0 : 2 : recipes/special_occasion/desserts
0 : 1 : recipes/special_occasion

1 : 4 : special_occasion/desserts/pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html
2 : 4 : desserts/pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html
3 : 4 : pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html

0 : 4 : recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/grandmas-chocolate-pie.html
1 : 3 : special_occasion/desserts/pie


**Im missing:
2 : 3 : special_occasion/desserts
1 : 2 : recipes/special_occasion
```

**

Comment: i admit it's a hard task :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example search for one dir:

```
$links = array(
    'http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/chocolate-pie.html',
    'http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/desserts/pie/cherry-pie.html',
    'http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/apps/chex-mix.html',
    'http://www.goodfood.com/recipes/special_occasion/soup/tomato.html',
    'http://www.goodfood.com/special/special_occasion/soup/beef-stew.html',
    'http://www.goodfood.com/special/special_occasion/soup/vegetable.html',
);

$dirs = array();
foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
    $urlPath = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $arrayUrlPath = explode('/', $urlPath);
    $dirs[$key] = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($arrayUrlPath as $dir) {
        if (empty($dir) || in_array(substr($dir, -5), array('.html'))) {
            continue;
        }
        $dirs[$key][$counter++] = $dir;
    }
}

$searchDirs = $dirs;

foreach ($searchDirs as $key => $dir) {
    foreach ($dir as $name) {
        echo 'dir: ' . $name . ', found in: ' . search($name, $key, $dirs) . "\n";
    }
}

function search($name, $excludeKey, $dirs)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach ($dirs as $key => $dir) {
        if ($key === $excludeKey) {
            continue;
        }
        if (in_array($name, $dir)) {
            $return[] = (int)$key + 1;
        }
    }
    return join(', ', $return);
}
```

If you want search longer strings rebuild `search` function, add `explode` for `$name` and comparision for `$key`, if dir is `aaa/bbb/ccc`, check on `index 0` is 'aaa' and on `index 1` is `bbb` and on `index 2` is `ccc`, unless move pointer `index+1` and check again.

I hope i helped.